# How to plot two maps side by side using pysal or geopandas?

Tags: python, maps, geopandas, pysal

I want to plot two tematic maps side by side to compare then. I am using geopandas to plot the maps and pysal to generate the maps from spatial analysis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create the subplots structure with matplotlib, and then add the plots with geopandas/pysal to the specific subplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
# add geopandas plot to left subplot
geodataframe.plot(..., ax=axes[0])
# add pysal plot to right subplot using `axes[1]`
```

Comment: I changed "nrows" to "ncols" and it worked. my intention was to plot them side by side. Thank you.

Comment: I worked but now they're tiny even if I set the figsize. How could I fix the size?

Answer (score 5):

In order to get two geopandas maps side by side, you can write:

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(20, 16))
ax1 = geodataframe.plot(ax=ax1, column='obs', legend=True)
ax2 = geodataframe.plot(ax=ax2, column='pred', legend=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import folium
import folium.plugins

m = folium.plugins.DualMap(location=(52.1, 5.1), tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom_start=8)

fg_both = folium.FeatureGroup(name='markers_both').add_to(m)
fg_1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='markers_1').add_to(m.m1)
fg_2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='markers_2').add_to(m.m2)

icon_red = folium.Icon(color='red')
folium.Marker((52.0, 5.0), tooltip='both', icon=icon_red).add_to(fg_both)
folium.Marker((52.4, 5.0), tooltip='1').add_to(fg_1)
folium.Marker((52.0, 5.4), tooltip='2').add_to(fg_2)

folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)
m
```

#output

[image]